# Show if $f(x)$ is measurable then $f(x+a)$ is also measurable

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Prove or Disprove: If $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ then for any scalar $a$, the function $g_a :\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}, g_a(x) = f(x+a)$ is measurable.

I'm pretty sure this is true because translates of measurable sets are measurable. but I'm having trouble showing it.
I know that since $f$ is measurable then for any $c$ in $\mathbb{R}$, 
$$\{x \in \mathbb{R}: f(x)<c\}$$ is measurable,   so does it follow directly that 
$$\{x-a \in \mathbb{R}: f(x+a)<c\} $$ is exactly the same set and therefore also measurable?

Comment: What does measurability of $f$ mean here? Is $f^{-1}(B)$ a Borel set for $B$ Borel or only guaranteed to be Lebesgue measurable?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your question (I really stink at measure theory).  I am using the Royden Fitzpatrick book, I assumed that the measurability of f meant the Lebesgue measure.  and I thought that all Borel sets were Lebesgue measurable.

Comment: Yes, every Borel set is Lebesgue measurable. But the converse is not true. It seems your definition is that $\{x\in\mathbb{R}:f(x)<r\}$ has to be Lebesgue measurable for each $r\in\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: I see what you mean,  I believe what your wrote is correct, (The book doesn't explicitly say,  however, the section is on Lebesgue measure)

Comment: you could also use the fact that the translation is actually a continuous mapping (on the reals, euclidean metric) (but I guess this is nothing you may assume?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $c \in \Bbb R$ and let $[h<c]$ denote the set $\{x \mid h(x) < c\}$.

$x \in [g_a<c] \iff g_a(x) < c \iff f(x+a) < c \iff x+a \in [f < c] \iff x \in [f<c] - a$

So, $[g_a<c] = [f<c] - a$. But since the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra $\Bbb L$ is closed under translations and $[f<c] \in \Bbb L$, we get $[f<c] - a\in \Bbb L$, so $[g_a<c] \in \Bbb L$.

Comment: This works, thanks! Just one question though, you say that the "Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra $\Bbb L$ is closed under translations"  but could I also say that the Lebesgue measure translation invariant?  That is, $m(\{x:f(x)<c\}) = m(\{x:f(x)<c\}-a)$ for all $a \in\mathbb{R}$ ?

Comment: @TheBean the Lebesgue measure is translation invariant, but this is not relevant here

Comment: @user258700 How to show that if $f$ is measurable and simple then $f(x+n)$ is measurable and simple.